# Safe Way to Include User Text Input in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security, razor

This feels like an easy one, but I'm having trouble finding the right search terms to get me what I need...

I have a requirement for part of my web page to display a previously-entered note from a user.  The note is saved in the database, and I am currently incorporating it using Razor like this:

```
<span>@Model.UserNote</span>
```

This works fine, but it gets my spidey senses tingling... what if the user decides that he wants his note to be something like `"</span><script>...</script><span>"`.  I know how to use parameters to avoid injection attacks in SQL Server, but is there an HTML equivalent or another approach to avoid saving or injecting malicious markup in HTML?  Displaying the text in a control like a textbox feels safer, but may not give me the visual appearance that I am looking for.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want to search for is cross-site scripting (xss).

The general solution is to encode output according to its context. For example if you are writing such data into plain html, you need html encoding, which is basically replacing < with & lt; and so on in dynamic data (~user input), so that everything only gets rendered as text. For a javascript context (for example *but not only* inside a `<script>` tag) you would need javascript encoding.

In .net, there is `HttpUtility` that includes such methods, eg. `HttpUtility.JavascriptStringEncode()`. Also there is the formerly separate AntiXSS library that can help by providing even stricter (whitelist-based) encoding, as opposed to the blacklist-based `HttpUtility`. So don't roll your own, it's trickier than it may first appear - just use a well-known implementation.

Also Razor has built-in protection against trivial xss attack vectors. By using @myVar, Razor automatically applies html encoding, so your code above is secure. Note that it would *not* be secure in a javascript context, where you need to apply javascript encoding yourself (ie. call the relevant method from `HttpUtility` for instance).

Note that without proper encoding, it is not more secure to use an input field or a textarea - an injection is an injection, doesn't matter much what characters need to be used if injection is possible.

Also slightly related, .net provides another protection besides the automatic html encoding. It uses "request validation", and by default won't allow request parameters (either get or post) to contain a less than character (<), immediately followed by a letter. Such a request would be blocked by the framework as potentially unsafe, unless this feature is deliberately turned off.

Your original example is blocked by both of these mechanisms (automatic encoding and request validation).

It's very important to note though, that in terms of xss, this is the very tip of the iceberg. While these protections in .net help somewhat, they are by no means sufficient in general. While your example is secure, in general you need to understand xss and what exactly these protections do to be able to produce secure code.